# Specify default @Bean without using @Primary Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

have a bean like this:

```
@Bean
TemplateEngine myTemplateEngine() {...}
```

But Spring boot also has a bean for TemplateEngine defined in:

> org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class

When I autowire TemplateEngine I get

> "Field required a single bean, but 2 were found"

I want the spring boot bean to be the default one and only use my bean if explicity specified, so I couldn't use @Primary annotation because I don't have access to that bean definition.

Also, I would like to avoid using xml configuration as well.

Comment: you need to use onconditional annotations , to make sure that your bean is picked when spring boots default fails

Answer (score 3):

Try to define your bean as

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(TemplateEngine .class)
TemplateEngine myTemplateEngine() {...}
```